# Working in multiple locations with different test IP's

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, ip-address, restsharp

So I am curious about people's solution to solve my problem. I work in different locations on one project and have different IP address (testing phase). Once completed I won't need this as I can throw to an exposed HTTP client endpoint.

My frustration is when I get to a new location and have to go through getting new addresses. Is there a simple pattern, solution to get the IP automatically and apply to my RESTSharp calls. ie

```
var client = new RestClient("http://192.168.0.0/API/getresult");
```

I would say this is common, but frustrating when you are showing a client progress but it crashes and need to re-apply corrections.

Comment: Why not store the correct location in a configuration file, then have code read that information from a configuration file? And you should avoid using IP addresses - that's what DNS is for.

Comment: Ok, will look into that. I am using a hidden API which was provided by client on a VM.